# EC2 Private IP changes on every server restart

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation, rhel

We have a RHEL 7.2 EC2 instance and we are trying to install Oracle 12C EE server. We have assigned an Elastic IP to the instance to make sure that the Public IP address does not change when we restart the server. But we saw that the hostname of the instance gets changed on a server restart.

**Problem:** There are a few steps in oracle installation where we need to mention the hostname of the EC2 instance (i.e. private DNS), so we are hardcoding the hostname during oracle installation. But the problem is if in case the hostname gets changed in every server restart then the installed software wont work (since it holds previous host name) - how to resolve this issue?

Please let us know on the best practices to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is your instance in a VPC? Private IP addresses for instances in a VPC do not change (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ip-addresses) across instance restarts. "A private IP address remains associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and restarted, and is released when the instance is terminated. "

Comment: I am using the default VPC. Will the private address change for default VPC on stop/start?

Comment: No, the private IP address will not change when the instance is in a VPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP addresses do not change in EC2 with a simple restart. They only change with a complete stop, followed later by a start. If you are using a VPC, which you most likely are, then the private IP address will not change even with a stop/start.

If you want a solution that will work even if you move the installation to a different EC2 instance, then you should create a Route53 private hosted zone, attach it to your VPC, and then create a custom DNS name for this server.

Comment: I am using the default VPC, have not configured any new VPC. Will the private IP change with a stop/start? Please comment.

Comment: @user182944 No. They don't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VPC (which is the default now) the private IP should not change upon restart or stop start.

My understanding is that you're having issue with hostname reset to the default ip-x-y-z-k upon os reboot causing issues with oracle database.
This is usually caused by cloud-init (embedded in the AMI).

I suggest you to go through these steps:

First set the hostname in your os:

```
$: hostnamectl set-hostname Your-New-Host-Name-Here --static
```

Edit your '**/etc/hosts**' to match the private IP:

```
<private_ip> <hostname>
```

Check the value of HOSTNAME in '**/etc/sysconfig/network**' it should match your hostname.

Finally, to solve the issue, I suggest to remove the following lines from '**/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg**'

- set_hostname
- update_hostname
- update_etc_host

To test if it works stop and start the instance, the private IP should stay the same as before and the hostname should be the one you defined.

I hope this helps.

G.